# Python ctypes: how to allocate output buffer for C function in callback

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, memory, ctypes

I have next callback as one of arguments in function in c-code:

```
typedef unsigned char* (*my_callback)(int size);
//for example:
unsigned char * tmp_buff = nullptr;
tmp_buff = i_alloc_fn(10);
printf("Tmp buff addr = %d.\n", tmp_buff);
*tmp_buff = 111;
printf("I am still alive");
```

I am trying to provide this callback from python (C-code is loaded as .so lib). I tried 2 ways.

```
ALLOC_CALLBACK_FUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int)
#...
def py_alloc_callback(size):
    libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6") 
    mem_ptr = libc.malloc(ctypes.c_uint(size))
    return mem_ptr
```

And

```
ALLOC_CALLBACK_FUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int)
stringbuffer = ''
#...
def py_alloc_callback(size):
    global stringbuffer
    stringbuffer=ctypes.create_string_buffer(size)

    return ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)(stringbuffer)
```

But both variants led to segmentation fault in C-code when it tried to write to allocated memory. 
Please, help me fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
mem_ptr = libc.malloc(ctypes.c_uint(size))
```

is clearly wrong. The parameter to `malloc` is of type `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works:

```
def py_alloc_callback(size):
    libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6") 
    alloc_f = libc.malloc
    alloc_f.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
    alloc_f.argtypes = [ ctypes.c_uint ] 
    return alloc_f(ctypes.c_uint(size))
```